# php insert file

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a php file for school. We have to take a form and add first name, last name, email and a photo to a database. I am able to add the names, email to the database but am unable to add the image name to the database. Here is part of the php code and some of the html. If someone can please take a look and give some help. Many thanks in advance.

```
<?php include("db_connect.php");?>
<?php  // select the database in which to add a table
mysql_select_db("final_exam_db",$con);



$sql ="INSERT INTO drivers_0115061 (ln,fn,month,day,year,photo,email) 
VALUES ('".$_POST["ln"]."',
    '".$_POST["fn"]."',
    '".$_POST["month"]."',
    '".$_POST["day"]."',
    '".$_POST["year"]."',
    '".$_POST['file']['photo']."',
    '".$_POST["email"]."'
    )";

//$sql="INSERT INTO people (fn,ln,dob,city,prov,pc,gender,hc,nod) VALUES ('steve','douglas',1234567,'winnipeg','manitoba','r3p 6g5','m','grey',2)";

//echo $sql;


mysql_query($sql, $con);
echo mysql_error();
?>




<?php include("db_close.php");?>

HTML:
<td>
Picture
</td>
<td>
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10000000"/>
<input type="file" id="photo" name="photo"/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
```

Comment: **What does "unable to add the image name to the database" mean?** "unable to add the image name to the database" is an inadequate description for us to understand the problem.  What happened when you tried it?  Did you get incorrect results?  Did you get *no* results?  If the results were incorrect, what made them incorrect?  What were you expecting instead?  Did you get *any* correct results?  If so, what were they? Did you get an error? Don't make us guess.

Comment: I had gotten no result. The first name, last name and email added to the database but the image name didn't. There was no error just no image name in the database.

Comment: the file name is in the $_FILES array, not the $_POST array. I assume you have a `<form ..` tag somewhere?

Answer (score -1):

Do it different way out

```
//be sure to add enctype in your form tag 
<form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file" id="file">
</form>
```

First handle your path and filename into database

```
    $allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
    $extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
    if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
    && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
    {
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
    {
    echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
    }
    else
    {
    //here is what actually you need to care , set your upload path from here
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
    "your/upload/path/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    }
    }
    }
    else
    {
    echo "Invalid file";
    }
```

if everything run well thats mean you uploaded a file successfully here you need to save your database record with your filename

And whenever you like to call your file do this
get filename from database

```
<img href="your/path/name/<?php echo $filenamefromdatabase; ?>" />
```